# vacauously true, logic question when there's no matching element

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

if $P(m)$ is true for all natural numbers $m_0 \le m \lt n$ then $P(n)$ is also true

(Given above statement, we are to prove $P(n)$ is true for all $n \ge m_0$
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3127180/291153)

The proof begins with $P(m_0)$ is vacously true.
And I wonder what "$P(m_0)$ is vacously true" means?

If we define
$Q(n) := P(m)$ is true for all $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+n$

We can rephrase the original statement
$Q(n) \implies P(m_0 + n)$

When $n=0$,
$P(m)$ is true for all $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+0$ because there's no such m to check if $P(m)$ is true

So we say $P(m_0)$ is true.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#Scope_of_the_concept
gives example where

$\forall x P(x) \implies Q(x) $
If there's no x that satisfies $P(x)$ then $Q(x)$ is true.

When there's no cell phones in a room, you can say cell phones in the room is turned off.

I can see, if there's nothing to talk about, there's no harm saying Q(x) is true because Q has also nothing to talk about.

Here we have something $m_0$ so that we say $P(m_0)$ is true.

So I can construct a better example with the cellphone.

If every cell phone in a room with serial number $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+n$ is mine then cell phone with serial number $m_0+n$ is mine

Since there's no phone in a room with serial number $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+0$, cell phone with serial number $m_0$ is mine .

So $m_0$ is mine is vacuously true.
What does it say?
How should I interpret it?
I can't go to a cellphone store and claim hey the phone with $m_0$ serial number is mine.

Another attempt...

Look mathematicians said,
statement of the form: for all x, $P(x) \implies Q(x)$
is always true when there's no x such that $P(x)$ is true.

Say $P(x)$ means x pays for a cellphone,
and $Q(x)$ means you give x a cellphone

If any x who pays for a cellphone, you give him a cellphone.
If there's no one who pays for a cellphone, the statement above is still true.
That's good, you can make a manual and put that statement into the manual.

Now, a given day, if sale is good so that you sell every m-th person $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+n$ , you are gonna give a cellphone for free to $m_0 +n$ th person

We can summarize the policy
$P(m)$ is true for all m in $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+n$ then $R(m_0+n)$.
Sounds like a good plan? deal? ok.

So $P(m)$ is true for all m in $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+0$, so $R(m_0)$
Now I know I'm the $m_0$-th customer today, so give me the free cellphone.

seller: what? I didn't say that?
me: no that's the deal, we have the mathematical proof?

What has gone wrong?
Or is it just the convention to interprete the above statement as I did?

I think I can tighten the policy $P(m)$ and $!P(m+1)$ is true for all m in $m_0 \le m \lt m_0+n$ then $R(m_0+n)$, but the argument still seems to hold.

edit)

I moved the following example down, because the above cellphone example is clearer.

if $q(t)$ is true for all t st $t_0 \leq t \lt t_0+n$ then $q(t_0+n)$ is true

what does it mean to say $q(t_0+0)$ is vacuously true?

Suppose $q(t)$ was defined by "there is no earth in time t"

Then we can say "there is no earth in time at $t_0$?
What does it mean when "there is no earth in time at $t_0$ is vacuously true?

Comment: Not very clear... if $q(t)$ is true for all $t$ st $t_0≤t<t_0+n$ then $q(t_0+0)=q(t_0)$ and thus is true according to the $\le$ in the inequality.

Comment: "Vacuously true" is used when the statement is true because there is nothing to check, usually when you are quantifying over an empty set like in your example: "for all $m$ such that $m_0\leq m <m_0$ we have ..."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA In the wikipedia example, there's no element such that Q(x) is true. So I can say ok, for a room where there's no cell phones, we can say all phones in the room are turned off. but here we are asserting there's element $m_0$ that satisfies $P(m_0)$ (that's one thing that seems differ.) I can follow the logic, but I guess I don't quite follow the intuition behind what it means by saying $P(m_0)$ is true

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank you. I added another example to better ask the question.

Comment: The statement "If $P(m)$ holds for $m_0\leq m<m_0+n$ then $P(n)$ also holds" is something you have to PROVE in any given circumstances, for the statement $P$ you have in mind, in order to prove $P$ by induction. It is not some universal statement that is always true. In particular, it is not true when $P(n)$ is your statement about the telephone, but it is true when $P(n)$ is a statement such as $\sum_{i=1}^n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek oh i added more context, that statement is given and we are to prove something

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I can see the flow, but I can't get the meaning of it.   (if Tokyo is in France, then the Eiffel Tower is in Bolivia) I can see the above conditional statement is true. But it seems like we are dealing with (if Tokyo is in France, then the Eiffel Tower is in Bolivia $\implies P(m)$ ) . I can accept the conditional assertion. But how come we can say $P(m)$ is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the "formal" expression of *Strong Induction* (see Tao I, **Proposition 2.2.14** (Strong principle of induction), page 28-29)?

The logical form is:

> $\forall m [\forall k (k < m \to P(k)) \to P(m)] \to \forall m P(m)$.

*I've considered for simplicity the special case with* $m_0=0$.

It is equivalent to The Principle of Mathematical induction (Tao's **Axiom 2.5**, page 19): *this needs several steps to be verified*.

What happens to the antecedent of the formula above when $m=0$?

We have that the formula amounts to:

(1) $\forall k (k < 0 \to P(k)) \to P(0)$.

We know, i.e. we prove it from arithmetical axioms, that $\lnot (k < 0)$.

Thus, using tautology: $\lnot P \to (P \to Q)$ in the form: $\lnot (k < 0) \to (k < 0 \to P(k))$ we get (by Modus Ponens and rules for removing and adding the universal quantifier):

(2) $\forall k (k < 0 \to P(k))$.

From (1) and (2), using again MP, we get: $P(0)$.

This is the reason behind Tao's comment [with $m_0$ in place of my $0$]:

> *In particular, this means that $P(m_0)$ is true, since in this case the hypothesis is vacuous.*"

Having said that, what we have proved is:

> > $\forall m [\forall k (k < m \to P(k)) \to P(m)] \vdash P(0)$.

For a full proof of SI form MI, see my answer to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4691291/proving-strong-induction/4691371#4691371).

Comment: Thank you. Can you elaborate "Now, using again MP, we get: (0)" ?  ..  the obvious modus ponens would look like $\forall$ ($k \gte 0 \to P(k)$) and $k=0$ \to $P(0)$.

Comment: So we are saying, "if P(k) is true for all k < m, p(m) is true" is true, and we know P(k) is true for all k < 0, because there's nothing to check for P(k). so by modus ponen, P(0) is true. I can follow.. 

But at the same time, I'm not getting it.. Maybe more direct question would be, I can see there's no harm saying "P(k) is true for all k < 0" since there's nothing to check. But using it to deduce something else seems like a hack I can't simply follow.

Comment: if Tokyo is in France, then the Eiffel Tower is in Bolivia. 
I can say yeah we can say that is a true statement

But I guess I feel there's no harm saying that is a false statement.   
So I feel like supposing it's a true statement is more like a decision (axiom) we have agreed on.  
So then isn't every statement based on axiom.. yes. but I am trying to answer what the uneasiness I feel is..

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm still struggling to understand "what my not-understanding" is. I've made my answer as of now. I'll have to think some more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this.

We are to prove strong induction

> $\forall m [\forall k (k < m \to P(k)) \to P(m)] \to \forall m P(m)$.

s1:

> $\forall k (k < m \to P(k)) \to P(m)$

In the problem we are given the above conditional as true statement.

for m = 0, we have the following form

s2: (vacuous truth)

> $A(m)$ is an empty set $\to P(m)$
> $m=0 \to A(m)$ is empty set

So with that proof structure, I can prove P(0) and ~P(0)
This seems weird, and I wanna know how I should interpret this.

You know $P(0)$ is true because you have the "s1" as a true statement. (Although how you got to know s1 is true is a mystery to me, I think using regular induction is the only way you got there)

So then, next question would be the following.
Let's say I accept the s3, s2 as truth.

s3: (strong induction)

> $\forall m [\forall k (k < m \to P(k)) \to P(m)] \to \forall m P(m)$.

Would there be no possibility of me proving s4, where W(m) is inconsistent with P(m)?

s4:

> $\forall m [\forall k (k < m \to W(k)) \to W(m)] \to \forall m W(m)$.

The question can be rephrased as,

s5: (regular induction)

> $P(0)$.
> whenever $P(n)$ is true, $P(n+1)$ is True

s6:

> $W(0)$.
> whenever $W(n)$ is true, $W(n+1)$ is True

s5 (regular induction), s2 (vacuous truth) implies s3 (strong induction).

conversly, s3 (strong induction), s2 (vacuous truth) can imply s5 (regular induction)

Is it possible for s3, s2 to imply s6? where the proposition(is it the right term? P(x)) to prove is inconsistent with s5 we proved earlier?

For a $P(x)$ statement we know how to construct, we can check the validity of it, but for some $P(x)$ can't be constructed so that we can check the validity.

Well in that case, I guess whether we can prove s5, s6 at the same time doesn't matter, since we have no way to know which one is true.

But there can be times where we just don't know how to construct P(x) yet?

```
And yet another question is, is this question a meaningful question?
```